# Preview print dialog defaults to Scale to Fit or Print Entire Image

Tags: macos, preview, printing

When printing a PDF file from Preview, the print dialog defaults to "Scale to Fit / Print Entire Image", and the default scale is some arbitrary number.  To get 100% scale requires clicking "Scale" and typing "100".

I want the default to be "Scale / 100%", without clicking or typing.  How can I do this in Yosemite?

This question was answered before under "[Keep Preview from autoresizing print output](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/2931/38539)" but the solution there does not seem to work under Yosemite.  Saving as a preset does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

As a run around, you can print it from terminal. Assuming your default printer is the one you want

```
lp -o fit-to-page /path/to/file.pdf
```

or by dragging and dropping the pdf onto the printer, which should print it at 100% and auto-rotated "fit to page". It depends on the pdf's size and rotation settings, but you'll find it works most of the time.

If you don't have you printer as a dock icon, you can find it in

```
~/Library/Printers/yourprintername
```